# Windows 10 Ubuntu 18.04 dual boot. Windows not shutting down properly

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, shutdown, dualboot

The problem occurs, when I boot into Ubuntu, shut Ubuntu down, boot into Windows, and shut Windows down. Then, it will not shut down as described by many other people. If I then turn off the machine by holding the power button and boot into Windows again, the problem doesn't occur anymore.

At the moment, I'm forced to boot Windows and Ubuntu multiple times a day, so this is not very convenient and also maybe not good for my laptop.

I've tried many things that worked for other people, but that do not work for me:

1. I turned off fast start-up in power settings.
2. In addition to 1, I also turned off the hibernation option in the command line via `powercfg.exe /hibernate off` and `powercfg -h off`
3. In addition to 1 and 2, I've forced a true shutdown in the command line with

   ```
   shutdown /s /t 0
   ```
4. In the device manager, system devices, Intel(R) Management Engine Interface, I de-selected allow to turn off in the power management properties.

Does anyone have further ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Doing a forced-off on your laptop should not harm the hardware... though it can (rarely) cause the files on your storage drive to get corrupted (not a fun day, but not particularly expensive to fix). As to your problem, I'm not sure. You've already done the things I would suggest. Hopefully someone else knows more

Comment: It sure doesn't help with what you posted with but " I'm forced to boot Windows and Ubuntu multiple times a day".. WSL is your friend.  It will save you from needing to do this entirely.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas, I don't know what WSL is. Besides, I'm not getting the problem with my remark. 1) It would be easier if 1 OS would do all what I need. 2) Every time I switch between the OSs, I need to wait to see if windows shuts down, which doesn't happen and then force it.

Comment: @CliffArmstrong, ok thanks for your comment on it not being harmful. That's already good to know.

Comment: WSL is the ["Windows Subsystem for Linux"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux).  It allows you to run one or more Linux distributions WITHOUT a VM.. NATIVE!  Right there in windows.  No, it's not like CYGWIN or MINGW64.. it runs the actual elf binaries from the actual distro.  You add packages with apt, zypper, or whatever the native package manager happens to be.  AND.. it isn't hard to get working.  I even use x11 GUI apps in windows using VcXsrv.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas,the purpose of my ubuntu system is using, automating and modifying OpenFOAM (OF). Will WSL not use some hardware resources? I'll be running very demanding models. I can't afford to loose resources on additional applications. In addition, I'll be using shell scripting to automate running OF, including sourcing modified code etc. These scripts should be transferable to my uni's supercomputer.Due to all problems I've seen on the short time that I use ubuntu, I'm a bit reluctant to start this endeavor by adding yet another application, WSL, that can cause additional issues

Comment: I have found that I get equal or better performance running things under WSL as long as those things aren't disk IO intensive. WSL isn't an endevor.. it's no big deal.. it's just another tool for your toolbox that is already built into your operating system.

Comment: With endeavor, I mean learning OpenFOAM, c++ and completing my research. Anyway, I prefer running a linux based OS by itself, not from windows. So if anyone can help me solve this dual boot issue, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

As a response to my own question, I want to write the following.

First of all, in addition to what I mentioned above about solutions that I tried, I'm not completely sure anymore that I didn't try anything else and hence made additional changes to my windows settings. In any case, nothing worked.

Anyway, recently I talked to an ITer, who suggested that using restart instead of shut down, can results in either windows or ubuntu to store some things in the RAM. After this, I started using shut down on both ubuntu and windows. And so far, the problem of windows hanging on shut down isn't occurring anymore.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm in the same boat: can shut down but not restart. However sometimes windows restarts b/c of an update, then I am hosed. I also dual boot, also turned off fast startup.

Comment: I'm not really sure, since I started using another computer and my new computer does not show the problem (I can easily use dual boot on the new computer). Did you try shutting down instead of restarting?

Answer (score 0):

Yea, shut down works fine (see my original comment). I ended up reinstalling Windows and the issue went away.